# How to troubleshoot zoomplot in R TeachingDemos package [Sailing Frisbee]

Tags: r

In the past I have used

```
zoomplot(locator(2))
```

from *library(TeachingDemos)* with much success but since upgrading to Sailing Frisbee (R3.0.2) I'm greeted by the error message:

```
Error in do.call(fn, alst) : invalid plot type.
```

Executing the stock-standard example (see below) provided in `?zoomplot` reproduces the error.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I may go about resolving this issue or as to an alternative course of action? I've restricted my searches to errors relating to this package but have come up empty-handed.

Many thanks.

```
library(TeachingDemos)
if(interactive()){

with(iris, plot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width,
                col=c('red','green','blue')[Species]))
text( 6.5, 1.5, 'test' )
zoomplot( locator(2) ) # now click on 2 points in the plot to zoom in

plot( 1:10, rnorm(10) )
tmp <- rnorm(10,1,3)
lines( (1:10) + 0.5, tmp, col='red' )
zoomplot( c(0,11), range(tmp) )
}
```